# How to select the score that is not null with the closest date

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a query in my access database. In this database I have a table called tblPCL that has 1000's of records and some patients have 3-4 PCL scores.

I need to write a query that will select one record from tblPCL for each patient that has a PCLScore that is not Null and that is the closest to today's date. I've been trying different combinations but this is the closest that I've gotten in my attempts. I tried to modify a code from another forum on here but I'm a bit confused with what I could be doing wrong.

I do also have criteria on my other variables in the query:
On PCLScore I have the criteria "Is Not Null" and on PCLStatus I have =1 because that will only bring up records that have a score.

My Table:
[image]

The error:
[image]

**Here is the syntax that I tried to write.**

```
(select from [tblPCL_PHQ]![VisitDate] where [tblPCL_PHQ]![VisitDate] > Date()
order by blPCL_PHQ]![PCLScore])
```

Please excuse my lack of SQL skills and thank you for any help in advanced.

Comment: mysql is not the same as ms access sql

Comment: You write "per patient"... where is the patient ID? Please post the complete SQL (copy it from the "SQL view" of the query you have).

Comment: If my answer helped, I would greatly appreciate it if you marked it as the accepted answer  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `select from` looks off. It should read `select [column_name1, column_name2, ...]` with the appropriate column names. Your where clause can select the row with most recent date by using

```
WHERE VisitDate = (SELECT MAX(VisitDate FROM [tableName] WHERE PCLScore IS NOT NULL)
```

assuming they're in the same table.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! =)